# Where is the error in my query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I wish I could give you more information from my investigation into the error, but  the most descriptive info I get is "You have an error in your SQL syntax".

```
CREATE TABLE jobs (
    id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    title VARCHAR (200), 
    descshort VARCHAR (400), 
    descr VARCHAR (7000), 
    postdate TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess you have an error in your SQL Syntax.
You forgot the closing ")"

```
CREATE TABLE jobs (
    id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    title VARCHAR (200), 
    descshort VARCHAR (400), 
    descr VARCHAR (7000), 
    postdate TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

Comment: Wow .. I'm an idiot. Too bad phpMyAdmin can't give me a more descriptive error so I don't waste time like this.

Answer (score 3):

You are missing a closing bracket.